# Where should [location] be dumped?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [location](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/location) tag is undefined and is used in numerous ways:

- file location
- memory location
- software/OS installation device
- locale
- GPS position
- IP address/VPN location
- geographical source of images
- location metadata
- icon placement on desktop
- method of detecting location
- wifi device positioning
- etc.

Many of these uses already have specific tags: [file-location](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-location), [network-location](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-location), [geolocation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/geolocation), [locale](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/locale), [desktop-icons](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-icons), various installation-related tags, [wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi) and [wifi-configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wifi-configuration).

Recommend deleting [location] and using the specific tags.  If necessary, create new specific tags.